# jQuery append() only certain columns

Tags: jquery, html-table, append

I have two tables on my page. The first one has three columns and the second one has two. The middle column on the first table is an image that when you click on it, it will move that row down to the second table. At the moment I have

```
$('table td img.add').live('click', (function() {
  $('table#tblName').append( $(this).closest('tr') );
}));
```

Which works. The row is removed from the first table and put at the bottom of the second. The only problem is that I want to only move the 1st and 3rd columns. I tried adding a middle column in the second table and then using jQuery to hide it when the page loaded, but as soon as I appended a row, that new row has three cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work.

```
$('table td img.add').live('click', (function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
  // remove the middle td
  $(this).closest('td').remove();
  $('table#tblName').append( parent );
}));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you possibly explain a bit? When I look at that it looks like "parent" is storing the current value of the tr, then in the second statement you remove the td of "$(this)" which I assume still refers to the image that was clicked on. Then the value of "parent" is appended to the second table. But the middle td was never removed from "parent".

Comment: Certainly. We are basically storing a reference to the parent, so parent isn't actually storing the values it's just pointing to the location in the webpage where the <tr>...</tr> is. Then as you said we remove the td of $(this) which is indeed still the image that was clicked on. Since parent is just a reference to the Dom, it no longer has the middle td.

Comment: Ahhh, I assumed the value of $(this)... was being stored in parent. Thank you so much for your help.